# Android: end infinite animation at start position

Tags: android, animation, user-interface

I use a infinite rotation animation in my Android app. If I call `cancelAnimation()` on the rotated `ImageView` the image goes immediately to the start position of the animation, without finalize the animation to that position. Is there a way to perform that, so that the user get a smoother experience without a break in the animation?

Comment: Did you use fillAfter()?  http://graphics-geek.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/mysterious-behavior-of-fillbefore.html

Answer (score 0):

you can put a flag. When you set the flag false, animation will stop. please look at the below code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ImageView img;
    Button btn, btn2;
    Animation myAnim;   
    boolean flag=true;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        myAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate);

        img.startAnimation(myAnim);

        myAnim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                System.out.println("onAnimationStart()");
            }

            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                if(flag)
                    System.out.println("onAnimationRepeat()");
                else
                    myAnim.cancel();
            }

            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                System.out.println("onAnimationEnd()");
            }
        });

        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                flag=false;
            }
        });

        btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 img.startAnimation(myAnim);
                 flag=true; 
            }
        });
    }

}
```